# Server refused our key というエラーで EC2 のインタンスに SSH で接続できない

Tags: aws, ssh, amazon-ec2

AWS　SSH接続について

・現状
AWS　EC2契約を行いました。インスタンスは正常に起動。
セキュリティ　インバウンド　で　SSHを許可、自身のIPアドレスも指定。
キーペアを作成。pemファイルをダウンロード。

・やりたいこと
AWSに対し　SSH接続およびSFTP接続を行いたい。

・状況と疑問
AWSで作成したpemをロードし、秘密鍵を作成。
それを使用し、AWSヘルプを参照しながら、puttyでSSH接続をおこなおうとしたところ、
ユーザ名を入力後、「 Server refused our key 」というメッセージが
Puttyで表示されSSH接続できませんでした。

秘密鍵の作成手順は
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html
を参照。
できたppkファイルをputty側で接続時に設定したのですが、上記のとおり
メッセージがでて、SSH接続は成功していません。

SSH接続を試した時のホスト名、ポート番号は間違っていません。
どの部分を確認したらよいでしょうか？

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/78528

Comment: マルチポスト　http://qiita.com/rtp/items/365384e894955b99d778

Answer (score 1):

ユーザ名が正しいか確認してみてください。

- Amazon Linux AMI : ec2-user
- RHEL AMI : ec2-user または root
- Ubuntu AMI : ubuntu または root
- Centos AMI : centos
- Fedora AMI : ec2-user
- SUSE : ec2-user または root
- 上記以外: AMI の作成元に確認してください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
ユーザ名は確認済です。
おそらく、鍵の作成もしくは読み込み（PuttyのAuth接続）あたりではないかと思いますが、このあたり具体的に詳しく知りたいです。
どうかお願いいたします。

Comment: Putty の Connection > SSH > Auth のところは ユーザガイドに画面キャプチャ付きでありますので ご確認してみてください。 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html#putty-ssh

Comment: EC2インスタンスはどのように作成しましたか？公開されているAMIを使ってますか？それとも独自のAMIを作ったのでしょうか？